# How to Foley bicycle?

Tags: foley, sound-effects-recording

I am currently recording some extra scenes for a post production project.

I was wondering if anyone has any tips or experience on recreating the sound with Foley techniques for a person riding a bicycle?

It is in the 3rd person perspective, the SSE was adamant about the pedal movement to be absolutely correct.

I am currently setting my bicycle up in the studio with its rear wheel raised off the floor so I can ride and imitate the movements.

I will also wild track some riding outside on the different types of surfaces to mix together later (tyre/surface samples etc..)

I'll be using an NTG-3 for the main mic, and i have also an sm58 to hand and the stereo pair on the zoom h4.

If anybody has more ideas to contribute, please free and thank heaps in advance!

Kind Regards;

Chris

Comment: All looks good. Having the bike upside down to record the pedal movement also works fine. You can then record gear changes and other clicks separately and edit them in. I'd also just record it all mono with your NTG3, no need to over complicate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your speedy reply. Yeah that's a great idea, I was thinking to try upside down also. I've currently got it raised on a car jack and some construction bricks. And I think I will take your advice on recording it all mono with just the shotgun! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recorded the very same sound effect, pretty much the way your doing it, but I set the bike up on a static trainer, so the back wheel was on two rollers and it sounded just like it was on a smooth path, the pedel movement sounded more laboured than it does when just turning the pedal by hand and it sounds just a little more realistic..you do need a friction trainer how ever, $50 on ebay?